# $O(n)/O(k)\times O(n-k) \simeq G(k, n)$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Prove that the manifolds $O(n)/_{O(k)\times O(n-k)}$ and $G(k, n)$ are diffeomorphic.

I can see easily that $\phi:O(n)/_{O(k)\times O(n-k)} \to G(k, n)$ defined by $[(v_1|...|v_n)]\mapsto <v_1,...,v_k>$ is a well defined bijection.

Now I'm supposed to prove that it is a local diffeomorphism, but I have no idea how to deal with the topology/differentiable structure of $O(n)/_{O(k)\times O(n-k)}$.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Try lifting $\phi$ to a map $\tilde{\phi}: O(n)\to G(k,n)$ and then showing that $\tilde{\phi}$ is invariant under the action of $O(k)\times O(n-k)$

Comment: But as I understand it, if $\tilde{\phi}$ is invariant under this action, then I can only conclude that $\phi$ is a bijection. I can't see how that gives me information about the differentiable structure...

Comment: The (natural) smooth structure on a quotient by a smooth action is constructed in such a way that a function is smooth on the quotient if and only if its lift to the whole space is smooth.

Comment: If a manifold is homogeneous under the smooth action of a Lie group $G$, then its is diffeormorphic to $G/G_x$, where $G_x$ is the stabilizer of some point. So what you have to check is that the agtion is smooth ; what is your definition of the Grassmanian ?